# How to save the stored procedure output to file when it's executed in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I want to save the stored procedure output directly to a file.

I have used the `BCP` command, but still its not saving the file.

This is the command using `BCP`:

```
bcp " SELECT TOP (1000) column FROM table " queryout "D:\spoutput.csv" -S servername -U username -P password -c -T
```

Comment: what do you get when you execute that command ? Any error messages ?

Comment: Have you tried choosing one authentication method? By using `-U username -P password` you're telling `bcp` to use SQL Server Login authentication, but you also give it `-T` which is telling it to use Windows authentication.

Comment: I am *guessing* you are using `xp_cmdshell` as a crutch to call `bcp`, to reconnect to the instance, to get the data and export it? Just *don't*. If you need to have the procedure also export the data have it call an SSIS package, or have it store the data in a table and a scheduled task can pick up that data and export it.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Powershell for this instead of BCP unless there's some feature of `bcp` that you specifically need it for. I may be in the minority, but I find `bcp` kind of clunky to work with. It's great for quickly loading data, but for more routine tasks like this, I prefer a different approach.

You can use `Invoke-SqlCmd` to execute any arbitrary SQL you want; in this case, a stored procedure. Then pipe the results of that to `Export-Csv` to directly write it to a file (you could also pipe it to `ConvertTo-Csv` if you wanted to work with the CSV more in Powershell).

I've found that most common things you can configure for outputting a file through `bcp` you can also do through PowerShell. And in fact, powershell can do some things `bcp` *cannot* such as handling quoting of fields.

```
# the server you want to run the proc on
$serverInstance = "localhost\lemur"
# the database the proc lives on
$database = "test"
# the path where you want the output file created
$outputFile = ".\output.csv"

# NOTE: You could do this in one go; I split it into multiple lines for clarity
$results = Invoke-SqlCmd -ServerInstance $serverInstance -Database $database -Query "exec dbo.GetDatabases"
$results | Export-Csv -Path $outputFile -Delimiter '|' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thanks a lot,
its working now i can export directly to the folder.